# Switching fragment wont work properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to switch fragments with an ontouchlistener set on the entire screen. I've done a lot of googling about how to switch fragment UIs, and thisseems to be the general answer; however, when I use this method it doesn't do anything except adds a somewhat transparent version of the fragment I want below my current UI, and then for some reason when I click on that fragment it takes me out of my current activity and goes to my last activity which is weird because I never added an Intent to switch activities.

```
public class suggestedfriends extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestedfriends,container, false);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Fragment newFragment = new profile();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.mainfragment, newFragment);

                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
      } 
 }

 public class profile extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment,container, false);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Fragment newFragment = new search();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.mainfragment, newFragment);


                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
      }
}
```

so I'm trying to switch from the first suggested friends fragment to the second profile fragment

Comment: what do you mean? the xml definitions? I defined profile as a normal xml linearlayout. I defined search as a linearlayout as well. I defined suggested friends differently. I defined it as a fragment within the main activity xml.

Comment: You probably don't want an `OnTouchListener` -- that gets fired for EVERY TOUCH EVENT, including every small movement of your finger; down, up, and move events, etc. Try an `OnClickListener` instead, and call `setClickable(true)` on your view if it's not a view that is clickable by default (e.g. `Button`, `ImageButton`).

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the actual app. This is just for a demonstration for funding purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use the `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of the `getFragmentManager()`

the child fragment manager is used inside fragments

Comment: btw does the childfragment manager still have the same methods as the normal manager or do I have to change "transaction"'s methods

Comment: You are welcome! :)
No you don't have to change anything, it works the same way. If it solved your problem you can set the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you let the activity manage the fragment transactions instead of caring about it inside the Fragment itself

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The second fragment is contained in the first fragment?

Comment: the first fragment is contained inside the main xml file and also has its own xml layout file. The second fragment just gets it's own xml layout file and then I inflate that when I start the second fragment.

Comment: R.id.mainfragment where is this resource? In the first fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use 'android.R.id.content' instead of your specific 'R.id.mainfragment'. You're specifically saying you want to switch from 'R.id.mainfragment" to the new fragment, which isn't always true.

'android.R.id.content' is a wildcard, implemented in the standard Android SDK, which is always valid (and should always be used in situations like these).

And you can also do the FragmentTransaction inline, which gives a much better code structure.

So your code would be like this:

```
public class suggestedfriends extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestedfriends, container, false);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Fragment newFragment = new profile();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });

    return view;
    }
}
```